# Bash and expect: can't reboot router via telnet

Tags: bash, networking, telnet, expect

I'm trying to reboot a D-Link router by connecting to it via telnet through expect.
The problem is that I can't execute (through the expect script) any of the commands supported by the router.

First of all, I show you a short telnet session with my router:

```
telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
BCM96338 ADSL Router
Login: admin
Password: 
> swversion show
EU_3-12-01-1R00.A2pB026.d20m
> logout

Bye bye. Have a nice day!!!
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Now I'm trying to make it automatic with an Expect script but I can't make it work. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#exp_internal 1
set timeout 30

#router username
set name admin

#command to execute
set routercmd "swversion show"

#router password
set pass mypassword

#router IP address
set routerip 192.168.1.1

spawn telnet $routerip
# send username & password
expect "Login: "
send "$name\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$pass\r"
expect "> "
send "$routercmd\r"
expect "> "
```

When I execute the script, it gets stuck at the password prompt:

```
./reboot_dut.sh 
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
BCM96338 ADSL Router
Login: admin
Password:
```

If I uncomment the #exp_internal 1 line I get:

```
./reboot_dut.sh 
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {6398}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no
Trying 192.168.1.1...
expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1..." (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no


expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1." (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no


expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no
Escape character is '^]'.
expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'." (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no


expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no
BCM96338 ADSL Router

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nBCM96338 ADSL Router\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? no
Login: 
expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nBCM96338 ADSL Router\r\nLogin: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Login: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nBCM96338 ADSL Router\r\nLogin: "
send: sending "admin\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password: "? no
a
expect: does "a" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password: "? no
dmin
Password: 
expect: does "admin\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "admin\r\nPassword: "
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "> "? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "swversion show\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "> "? no

> swversion show

expect: does "\r\n> swversion show\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "> "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "> "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n> "
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks stuck. Try an `autoexpect` session and see what the resulting script looks like.

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/fLVf2wL9 . The weird fact is that if I try to execute the expect script generated by autoexpect, it gets stuck again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I found the solution to the problem. The router I was trying to reboot was a D-LINK 2640B. A working expect script for this router is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet ROUTER_IP
match_max 10000
expect *login:*
sleep 2
send -- "USERNAME\r"
expect *assword:*
sleep 2
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
expect *>*
send -- "\r"
expect *>*
send -- "COMMAND\r"
expect *>*
send -- "\r"
expect *>*
send -- "logout\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to match your prompt to ">", as opposed to "> " (i.e. no space after it).

Comment: It doesn't print the return value of the command. Here is a pastebin with the debug info printed with the script modified as you suggested http://pastebin.com/HsNFc2Ka

Comment: Interesting... it seems the D-Link router only sends the prompt _after_ you have sent it the first command.
So what if you send _two_ carriage returns (instead of the ususal one) after you provide the password, would that help? Either `send "$pass\r\r"`, or in a separate send command.

Comment: One more thing... if I recall correctly, expect will only print the output to a command sent via `send` _with the next successful match operation_. So the reason you're not seeing any output is because there is no subsequent match after you sent the command. If my above suggestion (dual CR's) works, then you will need to do the same with your command (use two \r's), so that after receiving the command output expect will have a successful match. Makes sense?

Comment: I tried but it always gets stuck and says (after getting the password): expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern ">"? no

Comment: Ok, I see your question updated with the solution. That's some weird behavior from this D-Link router. Congrats for nailing it.
I see you ended up sending dual carriage returns, in separate send commands. Glad it helped!